# PHPUnit - Mock abstract function which is called in __construct of abstract class

Tags: php, mocking, phpunit, abstract-class

I have an abstract class like this.

```php
abstract class AbstractClassWithAbstractMethod
{
    public array $data;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->data = $this->getDataFromConcreteClass();
    }

    abstract protected function getDataFromConcreteClass(): array;
}
```

The intention is to get data from the concrete classes.

Now I'm trying to test this abstract class. Obviously, I need to mock the function `abstractMethod()`.
This is the simple test:

```php
class AbstractClassWithAbstractMethodTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testConstructorCallsAbstractMethod(): void
    {
        $mockBuilder = $this->getMockBuilder(AbstractClassWithAbstractMethod::class);
        $mockBuilder->onlyMethods(['getDataFromConcreteClass']);
        $mock = $mockBuilder->getMockForAbstractClass();

        $mock->expects($this->once())
             ->method('getDataFromConcreteClass')
             ->willReturn(['mocked', 'data']);

        $this->assertEquals(['mocked', 'data'], $mock->data);
    }
}
```

The result is `$mock->data` is an empty array. So I assume, that the mocked function will be added after the `__construct()` of the abstract class is called, which makes sense from the code of the mock creation.

What I am doing wrong? Is it even possible to mock abstract functions, which are used in the abstract classes `__construct()`?
I am also happy for tips and other ideas to get the data from the concrete classes.